Is there a way to keep wifi on during sleep mode?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04, i have switched off the power saving mode of WiFi, but still during sleep mode it gets disconnected first then during login it gets connected. I want the WiFi to not get disconnected, like in Windows.  is there any way to do this?     network adapter-Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31).Thanks.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. If the network remains active, the machine is technically not sleeping. Perhaps changing the lid-close action to “blank screen” will give you what you’re looking for?

@matigo
I've disabled the automatic suspend mode, but when i manually suspend the laptop, WiFi gets disconnected. I want the WiFi to work in suspend mode.
